# Joomla 3 - template only works with category, will not show single article

Tags: templates, joomla

If I set the menu link to be a category blog, it all works fine... but even if I remove all coding from the template 'index.php' file (besides  etc) and add one word, it doesn't work. Just shows a blank page.

e.g. 
http://dev.addrenaline.com/acces/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2&Itemid=101

*** I just realized there was a dedicated Joomla stack site - have posted this over there now...